# The confidence interval by the intercept with linear regression in R

Tags: r, statistics

Let's say that i have two variables **weight** and **age**, i have to find the confidence interval with level 99% by this case:

1. By the ordinate (Y-Axis), if we did a linear regression `a=lm(weight~age)`

I know that the ordinate is directly the **intercept** but why this won't work:

```
predict(a, newdata=data.frame(age=intercept), interval='confidence',
level=0.99)
```

Why this is incorrect? I would like to know the correct commands for these cases.

Comment: You say you want to find intervals for some observations, but you're actually interested in model parameters (intercept and slope)?

Comment: Well i have to find the confidence interval by the intercept and then by the slope, with that i should be able to get that interval, but the predict fucntion doesnt work for these case:/...

Comment: The confidence interval is just +/- the reported standard errors. So if you run `summary(a)`, you will return the coefficients and the associated s.e.'s. A confidence interval is the coefficient +/- the s.e. depending on the interval you are interested in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The broom package can return confidence intervals for regression model estimates.

```
require(broom)
A <- c(12,11,12,15,13,16,13,18,11,14)
B <- c(50,51,62,45,63,76,53,68,51,74)

model <- lm(A~B)

tidy(model, conf.int = TRUE, conf.level = 0.99)
         term  estimate  std.error statistic   p.value    conf.low conf.high
1 (Intercept) 6.8153948 3.75608761  1.814493 0.1071515 -5.78773401 19.418524
2           B 0.1127252 0.06240674  1.806299 0.1085031 -0.09667358  0.322124
```

EDIT:
I forgot that one can get confidence intervals for regression models in base R.

```
confint(model, level = .99)
                  0.5 %    99.5 %
(Intercept) -5.78773401 19.418524
B           -0.09667358  0.322124
```